# Custom login page in Spring security and jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

I have created the custom login page through spring security and jpa(MySql).It seems nothing happens when i click the submit button (Login credentials not validated from database). But default login page works well. I am get the attribute values from login page and sending to authentication

```
package com.tech.ems;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.*;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.*;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.*;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import com.tech.ems.service.UserDetailsServiceImpl;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return new UserDetailsServiceImpl();
}

@Bean
public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/css/**", "/images/**", "/WEB-INF/views/*")
            .permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
            .authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/")
            .usernameParameter("username")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/")
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/loginSuccess",true)
            .failureUrl("/loginSuccess")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll();
}
```

}

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%> 

<html> 
<head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> 
<link href="css/custom.css"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<html>
<body>
    <form action="loginSuccess" method="post">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <img src="images/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
        </div>

        <div class="logincontainer">
            <label for="username"><b>Username</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" id="username" required>

            <label for="password"><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password"  id="password" required>

            <button type="submit">Login</button>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" name="remember"> Remember me
            </label>
        </div>

        <div class="loginsubcontainer" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
            <button type="button" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
            <span class="psw"> <a href="#"> Forgot password?</a></span>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Can anyone let me know what i have missed

Comment: Hi, the loginPage, loginProcessingUrl, defaultSuccessUrl, failureUrl  don't look correct, here is a good example [spring-security-login](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login)

Comment: Thanks Dirk. But the problem here is the database hit is not happened seems. But if i remove the custom login page login credential validation working good.

Comment: please paste the code of your Controller and @RequestMapping url

Comment: @Autowired
 private UserProfileService userService;
 
 @GetMapping(value="/")
 public String loginPage(){
  return "login";
 }
 @PostMapping(value="/loginSuccess")
 public String loginSuccessPage(){
  return "loginsuccess";
 }